# Как получить доступ к аргументам, переданным таким образом? sum(1)(2)(3)

Tags: javascript

Например, `sum(1)(2)(3)` - должно возвращать сумму 1+2+3.
Как внутри функции sum получить доступ к 2 и 3?

Comment: Что такое `sum(1)(2)(3)`? Строка которую вы вводите в текстовый `input` или код `js`?

Comment: Код `js`, я ответила на свой вопрос, если возможно, посмотрите, пожалуйста, правильно ли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможное решение вопроса:

```js
function sum(m) {
    return function(n) {
        return function(k) {
          return m + n + k;
        }
    }
}

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3));
```

UPD.
Для случая, когда количество скобок неизвестно:

```js
function sum(n) {
 let currentSum = n;
 function f(m) {
  currentSum += m;
  return f;
 }

 f.toString = function() {
     return currentSum;
 };

 return f;
}

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)(5));
```

[Тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/sum-many-brackets) разбирается эта задача.

Comment: это называется каррирование, в вашем случае узконаправленное, потому что будет работать только с тремя скобками, в остальных случаях будет не совсем то, что вы, возможно, ожидаете

Comment: @ThisMan Если аргументы передаются именно таким образом, то это является ответом на вопрос.

Comment: @Anamnian ну а я что написал? _потому что будет работать только с тремя скобками, в остальных случаях будет не совсем то, что вы, возможно, ожидаете_

Comment: @ThisMan Ну автор же не говорила, что ожидает в других случаях. Я думаю не стоит в данном случае додумывать за нее.

Comment: @Anamnian я же написал, что при 3х скобках все будет работать, к чему ваши комментарии?

Comment: @Anamnian и на этот вопрос уже есть ответы ( да и вопросов таких куча )

Comment: @ThisMan спасибо, буду гуглить про каррирование.

Comment: @ThisMan заметка более чем справедлива. Я даже скажу что ожидал чтобы кто-нибудь опытный отпишется почему так происходит. Но мне кажется излишне было с вашей стороны предполагать чего ожидал, а чего не ожидал автор. В любом случае спасибо вам за пояснение!